# How to connect to FTP over TLS/SSL (FTPS) server in Java

Tags: java, ssl, ftp, ftps

I'm stuck in connecting to FTP over TLS/SSL (FTPS) server. I am using SimpleFTP library through am able to connect FTP server without SSL but could not connect FTPS.

It is giving me this error at line 2 (ftp.connect),

> SimpleFTP received an unknown response when connecting to the FTP server:
>   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------

and am using below code

```
SimpleFTP ftp = new SimpleFTP();

// Connect to an FTP server on port 21.
ftp.connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 21, "username", "pwd");
//getting error at (ftp.connect) above line

// Set binary mode.
ftp.bin();

// Change to a new working directory on the FTP server.
ftp.cwd("web");
ftp.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

*The `SimpleFTP` class/library does not support TLS/SSL at all.*

---

Use the [`FTPSClient` class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPSClient.html) from the [Apache Commons Net library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) instead.

See the [official example for the `FTPClient` class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) and just substitute the `FTPClient` with the `FTPSClient`.

```
FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient();
ftpClient.connect(host);
ftpClient.login(user, password);
```

---

The `FTPSClient` class defaults to an explicit TLS/SSL (recommended). In a rare case you need an implicit TLS/SSL, use [`new FTPSClient(true)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPSClient.html#%3Cinit%3E(boolean)).