# Using jsch to ftps to a Mainframe computer - fails to connect - but Filezilla works

Tags: java, ftp, jsch, mainframe, ftps

The error message is

com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Put file error: next step try connecting

```
   public void putFileWithPassword(String inputFileName, 
        String outputFileName, String host, int port, 
        String path, String user, String pswd) throws Exception{
    say("putFileWithPassword " + outputFileName + " " + host + " " + port + " " + user + " " + pswd);
    JSch jSch = new JSch();  
    Session session = jSch.getSession(user, host, port);
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.setPassword(pswd);
    response = "next step try connecting"+ " " + host + ":" + port + " " + user+" " + pswd;
    // WHAT ABOUT TLS CERTIFICATES?
    session.connect();
    response = "next step channel open";
```

To connect and transfer with Filezilla, we set Transfer type = ASCII, set Active Mode, and we used single quotes around the file name to place the file in the proper location on the mainframe.

I have read just about all of the current questions and answers in stackoverflow.com without any success.  I am thinking that I might need to use TLS Certificates, what ever they are.  Also, the jcraft.com site seems to be unavailable.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using PASV instead? Active means the data connection is initiated by the SERVER, which won't get through most firewalls.

Answer (score 0):

JSch is SFTP/SSH library.

While FTPS, Active mode, TLS certificates are all terms used with FTP(S) protocol, what is something completely different.

See:

- [How to connect to FTP over TLS/SSL (FTPS) server in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36302985/850848)
- [Secure FTP with org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12803942/850848)

Comment: I know what you are trying to say, but I think the crucial part is a bit hidden: you can't use a SFPT-client to connect to a FTPS-server since the two are completely different protocols.